# Proof that the probability that two boxes have the same number of balls approaches 0?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, limits, discrete-mathematics

You have $n$ distinguishable balls that you distribute with uniform probability into $k$ distinguishable boxes. Let $a$ and $b$ be two boxes. Let $num(a)$, $num(b)$ be the number of balls in $a$ and $b$ respectively.

How can one prove that, for a fixed $k$:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{P(num(a)=num(b))}=0$$

If anyone has a proof, or a paper that contains a proof, or knows of a book where a proof might be found, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

$k$ is fixed and ${n\to \infty}$. The limit we are trying to calculate is equals to $$\sum_{i=0}^{min([n/2], k-1)} P(num(a) = i) * P(num(b) = i)$$ which is equals to $$\sum_{i=0}^{min([n/2], k-1)} P(num(a) = i) ^ 2$$ $$P(num(a) = i) = \cfrac{{n-1 \choose k-i}}{{n \choose k}} = \cfrac{k * \cdots * ( k-i)}{n * (n -k+1) * \cdots * (n-k+i)}$$ For extremely large $n$ $min([n/2], k-1) = k$
So $$\sum_{i=0}^{min([n/2], k-1)} P(num(a) = i) * P(num(b) = i) = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} P(num(a) = i)^2 = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (\cfrac{k * \cdots * ( k-i)}{n * (n -k+1) * \cdots * (n-k+i)})^2 < {k * (\cfrac{k}{n})^2\to 0}$$

Comment: This doesn't seem right at all. Where does the min(n/2, k-1) come from? It is perfectly possible for the two boxes to both have up to n/2 balls in them. Secondly you can't square the probabilities as they are not independent. Thirdly your formula for P(num(a) = i) is wrong. I should be clear that both balls and the boxes are distinguishable. Finally, I think your final bound is wrong.